# What is the python code to read only full words in a text file ( lexical analysis to only detect whole words)?

Tags: python, lexical-analysis

I want to grab the groups of text that make up whole words in the spoken language (*Group of texts seperated by white spaces are considered as words*). For a example when I want to find the word *is* in a text file, even though the file does not contain the word is , the is inside the word s**is**ter is detected. I know a bit about ***lexical analysis*** but couldnt apply it to my project. Can some one provide the python code for this case.

This is the code that I used but it caused the above problem.

```
 words_to_find = ("test1", "test2", "test3")
    line = 0
    #User_Input.txt is a file saved in my computer which i used as the input of the system 
    with open("User_Input.txt", "r") as f:
        txt = f.readline()
        line += 1
        for word in words_to_find:
            if word in txt:
                print(F"Word: '{word}' found at line {line}, " 
                      F"pos: {txt.index(word)}")
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use [spacy](https://spacy.io) to tokenize your list, as natural language tends to be tricky, with all its exceptions and what nots:

```
from spacy.lang.en import English

nlp = English()
# Create a Tokenizer with the default settings for English
# including punctuation rules and exceptions
tokenizer = nlp.Defaults.create_tokenizer(nlp)
txt = f.readlines()
line += 1
for txt_line in txt:
    [print(f'Word {word} found at line {line}; pos: {txt.index(word)}') for word in nlp(txt)]
```

Alternatively, you could use [textblob](https://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/) in the following way:

```
# from textblob import TextBlob
txt = f.readlines()
blob = TextBlob(txt)
for index, word in enumerate(list(blob.words)):
    line = line + 1
    print(f'Word {word.text} found in position {index} at line {line}')
```

Comment: As @dyz points out, nltk can also be used, but I just prefer spacy as its syntax is more up-to-date. If you'd like another option, you can look into [textblob](https://textblob.readthedocs.io/) and the second example I've provided.

Answer (score 1):

Use `nltk` to tokenize your text in a robust way. Also, keep in mind the words in the text may be in mixed case. Convert them to the lower case before searching.

```
import nltk
words = nltk.word_tokenize(txt.lower())
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions in general, and the `\b` term specifically, which means "word boundary" is the way I separate words from other arbitrary characters.  Here's an example:

```
import re
 
# words with arbitrary characters in between
data = """now is;  the time for, all-good-men
to come\t to the, aid of 
their... country"""

exp = re.compile(r"\b\w+")

pos = 0
while True:
    m = exp.search(data, pos)
    if not m:
        break
    print(m.group(0))
    pos = m.end(0)
```

Result:

```
now
is
the
time
for
all
good
men
to
come
to
the
aid
of
their
country
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a RegEx:

```py
import re

words_to_find = ["test1", "test2", "test3"] # converted this to a list to use `in`
line = 0
with open("User_Input.txt", "r") as f:
  txt = f.readline()
  line += 1
  rx = re.findall('(\w+)', txt) # rx will be a list containing all the words in `txt`

  # you can iterate for every word in a line
  for word in rx: # for every word in the RegEx list
    if word in words_to_find: print(word)

    # or you can iterate through your search case only
    # note that this will find only the first occurance of each word in `words_to_find`
    for word in words_to_find # `test1`, `test2`, `test3`...
      if word in rx: print(word) # if `test1` is present in this line's list of words...
```

What the above code does it apply the `(\w+)` RegEx on your text string and return the list of matches. In this case, the RegEx will match any word separated by spaces.

Useful resources: [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/) for testing RegExes, [Python RegExes](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp) and [RegExr](https://regexr.com/) for learning more about regular expressions.

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to find the words test1, test2, or test3 in the text file, you shouldn't need to manually increment the line value. Assuming the text file contains each word on a separate line, the following code works

```
words_to_find = ("test1", "test2", "test3")
file = open("User_Input.txt", "r").readlines()
for line in file:
    txt = line.strip('\n')
    for word in words_to_find:
        if word in txt:
            print(F"Word: '{word}' found at line {file.index(line)+1}, "F"pos: {txt.index(word)}")
```

I don't know what position is meant to signify though.

Answer (score -2):

Just put the spaces in the string arguments, I think.

Comment: Cant believe I spend 5+ hours trying to find a fix! Thx man :)

Comment: Spaces will prevent words to be found in the vicinity of punctuation, in particular at the end of the sentence.